# create file using javascript at local machine

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hello I have below mention code to create txt file at local drive using Firefox browser but it does not work please help me out of these

```
function WriteTest() {
    var sFileContent="Dhaval Patel Tried to make life easy";
    var sFilePath="C:/Users/Dhaval Patel/Desktop/RFQ Forms/Test.txt";
    alert(sFilePath +"  "+sFileContent);
    try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
    }   
    catch (e) {
        alert("Permission UniversalXPConnect denied.");
    }
    file=Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(sFilePath);
    file.createUnique(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE,420);
    outputStream=Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
    outputStream.init(file,0x04|0x08|0x20,420,0);
    outputStream.write(sFileContent, sFileContent.length);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? What alerts are shown? What error messages on the JavaScript console?

Comment: This is for an addon, right? Have you looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets%252FFile_I%252FO#Write_a_string)?

Comment: Documentation on the XPCOM interface is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile) (_nsILocalFile_ was merged with _nsIFile_ in Gecko 14).

Comment: [`enablePrivelege` is dead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bypassing_Security_Restrictions_and_Signing_Code).

But you can test snippets of privileged code with [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad)